# Async calls in blazor app hang forever and never error

Tags: c#, asynchronous, client, blazor

I am trying to call an async method in a cs class and the page just freezes.
When debugging this, everything seems to run fine till the `await thing.wait.WaitAsync();` line. After that line no other breakpoint gets hit (I have a bunch of breakpoints around, including one on the next line), the page looks like it keeps loading and no error/exception message pops up.

ApiClient_Test.razor

```
@if (myResult == null)
{
    <p><em>Loading...</em></p>
}
else
{
    <p>@myResult</p>
}
@code{
    private string myResult;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
    var test = new ApiClient_BlazorTest.ApiClientBlazorTests.ApiClient_TestAsync();
    myResult = test.MyMethod();
    }
}
```

ApiClientTest.cs

```
namespace ApiClient_BlazorTest.ApiClientBlazorTests
{
    public class ApiClient_TestAsync : Controller
    {
        public string MyMethod()
        {
            var a = MyAsyncMethod();
            a.Wait();

            return a.Result;
        }

        public async Task<string> MyAsyncMethod()
        {
            var thing = new athing();

            // start a thing that takes 6 seconds
            thing.dothings();
            // await the thing
            await thing.wait.WaitAsync();
            return "ok";
        }

        private class athing
        {
            public SemaphoreSlim wait { get; set; } = new SemaphoreSlim(1);
            public string dothings()
            {
                wait.Wait();
                Task.Run(() => { Thread.Sleep(6000); wait.Release(); });
                return "";
            }
        }   
    }
}
```

I ran the same code on a console app. Everything worked perfectly fine there.

Had anyone seen something like this before with blazor and async functions?

Comment: A Console app is _very_ different with respect to async.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Blazor render has a `SynchronizationContext`, so [blocking on asynchronous code can cause a deadlock](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html).

The best solution is to remove all blocking calls - i.e., use `await` instead of `Wait()` or `Result`:

```
public async Task<string> MyMethodAsync() // was `public string MyMethod()`
{
  var a = MyAsyncMethod();
  // await a; // was `a.Wait();`

  return await a; // was `return a.Result;`
}
```

> I ran the same code on a console app. Everything worked perfectly fine there.

Console applications do not have a `SynchronizationContext`, so this deadlock does not happen in that environment.